# php 7.1 warning "A non-numeric value" only for numeric values "0-4"

Tags: php

I have the following working code:

```
$nif = 'A12345678';

$even = $nif[2] + $nif[4] + $nif[6];

for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i += 2)
{
    echo $nif[$i];
    $even += substr((2 * $nif[$i]), 0, 1) + substr((2 * $nif[$i]), 1, 1);
}
```

Output for PHP 7.0.14

```
1357
```

Output for PHP 7.1

```
1<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  A non-numeric value encountered in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
3<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  A non-numeric value encountered in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
57
```

Now if I change the value of `$nif` to:

```
$nif = 'A52545678';
```

The output for 7.1 would be:

```
5557
```

Already tried passing a normal variable to `substr()` but that's not the problem:

```
$a = $nif[$i];
$even += substr((2 * $a), 0, 1) + substr((2 * $a), 1, 1);
```

Why is PHP 7.1 or `substr()` from PHP 7.1 treating numeric values in the range `'0-4'` as non-numeric values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the following part of the code:

```
substr((2 * $nif[$i]), 1, 1)
```

1. for `$i = 1;`, `2 * $nif[$i]` will yield `2`.
2. `2` gets casted to a string by `substr()` as it tries to extract the second character, which doesn't exist, since the string is `'2'`
3. `substr()` yields an empty string
4. the empty string `''` is passed to the `+` operator, which produces the *A non-numeric value encountered* warning, since an empty string is not a valid numeric string.

The reason it works with `5` and `7` is that in step 2 `substr()` will operate on a 2-character string instead of 1-character string and will thus yield a valid numeric string.

This warning is new in PHP 7.1, according to [Migrating from PHP 7.0.x to PHP 7.1.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php):

> **Notices and warnings on arithmetic with invalid strings**
>
> New **E_WARNING** and **E_NOTICE** errors have been introduced when invalid strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers (+ - * / ** % << >> | & ^) or their assignment equivalents. An **E_NOTICE** is emitted when the string begins with a numeric value but contains trailing non-numeric characters, and an **E_WARNING** is emitted when the string does not contain a numeric value.

You can circumvent this with explicit `(int)` casts before the `substr()` calls:

```
(int) substr((2 * $nif[$i]), 1, 1)
```

Comment: `$nif` is actually already a string .. note `$nif = 'A12345678';`

Comment: But, the question is: Why only happens with `0-4` and not with `5-9`?

Comment: Because with 5 - 9 `substr()` operates on a 2-digit number, which it can cast to a string and extract the second character of, yielding a valid numeric string, not an empty string as with 1 - 4.

Comment: If you test the OP's code you get this error message ONCE each time through the loop. So the error is generated for each time the `+` (addition) is done.

Comment: No, you get the error twice (for 1 and 3). For 5 and 7 it does not produce a warning for reasons I've already stated.

Comment: This is correct, you should add the reason why errors show in 7.1.

Comment: Would be worth adding that the reason it generates errors in `PHP7.1` is `New E_WARNING and E_NOTICE errors have been introduced when invalid strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers (+ - * / ** % << >> | & ^) or their assignment equivalents. An E_NOTICE is emitted when the string begins with a numeric value but contains trailing non-numeric characters, and an E_WARNING is emitted when the string does not contain a numeric value. `